# How to detect that my application lost focus in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qt5, qevent

I'm displaying a popup window when the mouse cursor is over a certain widget and I'd like to hide this popup when the mouse leaves the widget.

To do it, I reimplemented `leaveEvent()`. This seems to work in all cases except when switching to another application by `Alt+Tab`. I figured out that I probably need to catch another event, but somehow I can't find the proper one. Can you suggest one?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The event you are looking for is `QEvent::ApplicationDeactivate`: "The application has been suspended, and is unavailable to the user".

You can install an event filter on your `QApplication` instance to catch this event. See the documentation for [`QObject::installEventFilter(QObject*)`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#installEventFilter) for more details how this works.

Since Qt 5.2 the `QEvent::ApplicationDeactivate` event is deprecated. The correct way to identify when an application is deactivated in Qt 5.2 (or later) is to use the [`QGuiApplication::applicationStateChanged(Qt::ApplicationState state)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qguiapplication.html#applicationStateChanged) signal.

Comment: Thanks. Inspired by your suggestion, I found that it was enough to catch both QEvent::Leave and QEvent::WindowDeactivate events in my eventFilter and hide my popup on either of these.