# Detecting click outside QWidget

Tags: qt

My application has non-rectangular popup widgets.

their class defines the following to achieve that transparency:

```
setAttribute(Qt::WA_NoSystemBackground, true);
setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground, true);
```

I also use:

```
 this->setWindowFlags(Qt::Popup| Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
```

The problem is that on windows 7, an automatic "shadow" is being drawn on the bottom and right  sides of my window. This is highly undesirable.

So, I tried using Qt::Tool instead of Qt::Popup

```
 this->setWindowFlags(Qt::Tool | Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
```

This works visually. No shadow, but now a mouse click outside my widget window will not automatically close/hide it as it would have done with a Qt::Popup.

So, I need one of these two solutions:

1. A way to have Qt::Popup **and** get rid of that automatic windows shadow decoration
2. A way to let the Qt::Tool window a mouse click occurred outside of it.

*One note: My application is built for Windows XP and up. I cannot use a Vista/Win7 only runtime DLLs, nor can i have a "Windows XP" and "Vista and up" separate builds.*

Any advice will be welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally after realizing that no amount of "SetFocusPolicy" calls will allow me to receive those events for a Qt::Tool window, I've resorted to something else to fix my problem:

1. I kept the Qt:tool as Qt::Popup caused an undesired shadowing effect, tarnishing my owner draw frame. Removing this style cannot be done in Qt and I didn't want to mess with platform specific conditional code.
2. I installed an event filter with my Qt::tool window and I began receiving events that assisted me in understanding when other parts of my application were clicked, or if the application itself lost focus to another application. This was what I needed, functionality wise. I could also get an event when users click the non-client areas of the application's main window, such as the windows caption so that I can close it when dragging begins etc.

Comment: Qt::WindowType::NoDropShadowWindowHint can erase the shadow effect

Answer (score 1):

You could manually watch for when the focus changes from your `Qt::Tool` window. So basically you watch for when the focus goes onto another window of your process or when your application loses focus.

[How to detect that my application lost focus in Qt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14147304/how-to-detect-that-my-application-lost-focus-in-qt)

Hope that helps.

Comment: Qt:tool does not receive focusOutEvent if I click on the frame of its parent widget. Only Qt::Popup does that.

Comment: You have to set the focus policy for it to receive focus events: `this->setFocusPolicy(Qt::ClickFocus);`

Answer (score 1):

My solution for Windows 7:

```
QDialog *d = new QDialog;
d->setStyleSheet("background:transparent;");
d->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose, true);
d->setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground, true);
#ifdef Q_OS_WIN
d->createWinId();
#endif
d->setWindowFlags(Qt::Popup | Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
d->show();
```

Answer (score 0):

I set my QListView

```
d->setWindowFlags(Qt::Popup | Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
```

Install eventfilter and used MousePressEvent to hide qlistview widget.

MousePressEvent on list never comes to filter they produce other events which I didn't debug.

So if you want to design auto completer this will be perfect. Tested in Qt5.3.1.